# ¿implementar performClick en android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]cuando uso el setOnTouchListener en un botón, al sobrescribir el metodo onTouch me dice esto

> Vista personalizada ImageView tiene activado setOnTouchListener pero no reemplaza performClick Si una vista que anula onTouchEvent o utiliza un OnTouchListener no implementa también performClick y lo llama cuando se detectan los clics, es posible que la vista no maneje las acciones de accesibilidad correctamente. La lógica que maneja las acciones de clic idealmente debería colocarse en Ver # performClick ya que algunos servicios de accesibilidad invocan performClick cuando debería producirse una acción de clic

he buscado de todo y no encuentro como quitar el warning.

Este es mi codigo:

```
boton_w.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                boton_w.setElevation(2);

            }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                boton_w.setElevation(10);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

asi es como me marca el warning

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que es lo que quieres conseguir ?

Comment: que me deje de dar el warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, intenta llamar al método performClick de esta manera:

```
boton_w.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
             switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 boton_w.setElevation(2);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                view.performClick();
                boton_w.setElevation(10);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });




 boton_f.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                 switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     boton_f.setElevation(2);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    view.performClick();
                    boton_f.setElevation(10);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Al parecer con Android Studio 3.0 aparecen esos warnings, puedes hacerlo de otra manera:

```
boton_f.setOnTouchListener(this);
boton_w.setOnTouchListener(this);


public class TuActividad extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {


 ...
      @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        //int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (v.getId() == boton_w.getId()){
                 boton_w.setElevation(2);
             } else {
                boton_f.setElevation(2);
             }
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.performClick();
                   if (v.getId() == boton_w.getId()){
                         boton_w.setElevation(10);
                     } else {
                        boton_f.setElevation(10);
                     }
        break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Aun así sigue la advertencia

Comment: estas seguro ? incluso llamando a view.performClick(); ?

Comment: espera, veo que tienes 2 botones, haz el cambio en los 2 botones

Comment: sigue igual, antes de la versión actual de android funcionaba bien

Comment: acabo de actualizar mi respuesta

Comment: wow amigo muchas gracias :D